Method hiding instead of static virtual C++
I want to create a utility class (which are usually static) and combine it with OOP's abstraction.
My question is: is it a good practice to use method hiding to combine abstraction with static,
as C++ does not allow static virtual?
class Sort {
private:
    static void sort(int *arr, int size);
};

class SelectSort: public Sort {
public:
    static void sort(int *arr, int size);
};


class InsertSort: public Sort {
public:
    static void sort(int *arr, int size);
};

So we have a Sort class that mimics Java's Interface.
-> We say: "everything that inherits Sort class should have sort() method"
-> Additionally, we do not need instances of Sorting classes, so they're made static.
Now, we can call the static utility method without creating an instance of the class, and also used  abstraction.
SelectSort::sort(arr, length);
I've tried making static method virtual
class Sort {
private:
    virtual static void sort(int *arr, int size);
};

And have got the following error:
error: member ‘sort’ cannot be declared both ‘virtual’ and ‘static’
Should I use method hiding or should I not bother and just pick one concept - either make sorting static or use polymorphism?
I know method hiding is not true polymorphism, but we can imitate polymorphism in cases where it is not allowed by language's semantics.
I used it for the programmer to know rather than for the compiler.
My question is more about correct design approach. My guess is that all three solutions (static, polymorphism, method hiding) are valid. But which is a more preferable approach?

How will you be calling your different static method hiding?

IMHO, when you only need to define how a single function looks like, why would you need classes? Instead, you could just define how sort functions look like, e.g., with typedef void (*SortFunction) (int*, int); or typedef std::function<void(int*, int)> SortFunction;.

So we have a Sort class that mimics Java's Interface. -- If you are using Java as a model in writing C++ code, better to not do this.  Use C++'s best practices and idioms -- for example, note you mentioned nothing about using templates.  You basically want to implement the Strategy design pattern, but using C++.

@PaulMcKenzie, thank you, understood

Just use free functions (no class needed), but add a namespace. Also passing your array like this int *arr, int size); is "C" style coding... do NOT do that. Use std::span<int> (or use iterators).  At least have a look at how std::sort  is designed. E.g. you can end up with something like namespace myAlgorithms { void SelectSort(std::span<int> data); } }

Can you also tell us WHAT you want to achieve? Do you want to model a collection of sort functions, or do you want to be able to call another function with a sort strategy?

@PepijnKramer, I guess I wanted to implement different sorting functions in Java-style, my rationale was to create a class and use a Strategy pattern or to make the functions static, because in Java everything is a class. Now I realize that in C++ I am not strictly forced to follow OOP everywhere, and I guess I can implement it in a procedural-style?

@PepijnKramer I wanted to use abstractions and also make utility functions static (as it is a good practice?). But virtual static are not allowed in C++. And I thought of Sort parent class as of an Interface in Java. My rationale was to mimic an Interface and combine it with static by using method hiding. But method hiding is made for completely something else. So I ended up thinking in Java-style but in C++, which, from the comments, is a no-no.

Yes OO in C++ is a tool, functional is definitely an option too. And then there is also static polymorphism (concepts, class templates).  And things like std::function

what do you expect to gain from the inheritance? Its not obvious. Polymorphism? How?

Example of using std::function to be able to pass customized sort functions to another function
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

namespace myAlgorithms
{
    
void quick_sort_sort(std::span<int> data)
{
}

void bubble_sort(std::span<int> data)
{
}

} //namespace myAlgorithms

void function_using_sort_function(std::span<int> values, std::function<void(std::span<int>) sorter )
{
    
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{5,7,4,3,1,8};
    function_using_sort_function(values,myAlgorithms::bubble_sort);
}

